# How to get data in the controller and pass it to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First of all, I need to know how I can get a row from the database by some how using the URL{id} as the value that I need, to query my database for the TripId. Once I have that I then need to pass it to the view.

In my controller I was looking for the tripid value '1' just to see if I could get that displaying on my view. but i expect that is where I would have a more complex query

Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the controller

```
public class TripsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    ActionResult View(int id)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            var trip = (from Trips in _db.Trips
                         where Trips.TripId.Equals('1')
                         select Trips.TripId);
            if (trip == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            } else
            {
                /// Code to display page?
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
public class Trips
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TripId { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int CoachId { get; set; }

}
```

}

And lastly the view..

```
@model _MVCCoachTravelling.Models.Trips
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "View";

}

<div class="main-container">

<div class="row">

      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
            <div class="caption-full">
                <h4 class="pull-right">£@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</h4>
                <h4>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
                </h4>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)</p>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query fails it is because you are comparing a char to an int

```
where Trips.TripId.Equals('1')
```

You should instead compare

```
where Trips.TripId == 1
```

Once you get your trip it is now `return View(trip)`.

```
public ActionResult ViewTrip(int id)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var query = from t in db.Trips
                    where t.TripId == id
                    select t;

        var trip = query.FirstOrDefault();

        if (trip == null) { /* fail */ }

        return View(trip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops didn't know about that! Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:

```
ActionResult View(int id)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var trip = (from Trips in _db.Trips where Trips.TripId.Equals('1') select Trips.TripId);

        if (trip == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View()
    }
}
```

Provided your view is correctly mapped to a controller and model.